# Importing Data from R to excel

Tags: r, excel

I tried this code to get a data file from R into an excel file  write.table(T1h1,file="table.xls").

When I opened the excel file it looks like this

```
T1h11 19198.7
T1h12 21090.7
T1h13 20474
T1h14 19557.3
T1h15 35335.3
T1h16 37534
T1h17 23355.3
T1h18 28823.3
T1h19 24003.3
T1h110 14978.7
T1h111 32976.7
T1h112 22928.7
T1h113 13316.7
T1h114 26042.7
T1h115 11271.3
```

Is there any way to get just the data without the row number such as T1h11, T1h12, T1h13 etc.

Comment: You can't use `write.table` to produce an Excel (.xls) file. Try `write.csv` for a probably better alternative to produce a .csv. And set `row.names=FALSE`.

Comment: Thank you Thomas, It just produced the file the way I wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.** As long as your data frame only has one column then this works (at least it does work on Excel 2013 under Windows which is what I am using); however, assuming you started Excel by entering `DF.xls` into the Windows cmd line or double clicking on `DF.xls` in Windows Explorer when Excel starts it will warn you that the file is not a real `xls` file and you can click on Yes or No to allow it to read it anyways or not:

```
DF <- data.frame(a = 1:3, row.names = letters[1:3])
write.table(DF, file = "DF.xls", row.names = FALSE)
```

**2.** If more than one column exists then the above will result in Excel reading all the columns into a single Excel column.  This is not very useful so in that case replace the last line with:

```
write.csv(DF, file = "DF.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

in which case Excel will read it in as a csv file.

**3.** See this [R wiki page](http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=tips%3adata-io%3ams_windows) for more options.